# how to display osm map

Tags: android

I have a tab tab, and on clicking on this tab, I want to set a content as OSM Map( its setContent() ). I am doing this :

```
View bottomMap = createBottomTabView(bottomTabHost.getContext(), "Map", R.drawable.map);
bottomTabHost.addTab(bottomTabHost.newTabSpec("Map").setIndicator(bottomMap).setContent(new Intent(this, OSMMapClass.class)));

public class MapBottomTab extends MapActivity 
{
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
      {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         org.osmdroid.views.MapView mapView = new org.osmdroid.views.MapView(this, 256);
         setContentView(mapView);
      }
}
```

What should be the changes to load the Map...??

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define the map layout in the xml in a LinearLayout for example like this

```
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mapLayoutFinal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <!-- you do your map layout (<org.osmdroid.views.MapView ... /> ) -->

    </LinearLayout>
```

and then you declare this layout in your activity on create method like this :

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_fragment);
LinearLayout rl = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mapLayoutFinal);
    this.mOsmv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    rl.addView(mOsmv);
```

this should work.
PS: I work with an ofline osmdroid and I jaust define everything in the activity and only a linear layout where I paste my view there.